# Software flashing attiny167 from RPi with avrdude

Tags: usb, attiny, avrdude, flash, raspberrypi

I am trying to flash a program onto an attiny167
(already bootloaded with the [micronucleus bootloader](https://github.com/micronucleus/micronucleus))
with a Raspberry Pi via avrdude and USB.

## Background

I have 50 Raspberry Pi 3B's connected to an amazon server collecting data.

I have 50 custom attiny167 based USB sensor PCBs which I will connect to the Pis
via USB ([see this previous issue for more detail](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/280993/how-to-write-bootloader-and-drivers-to-attiny167?noredirect=1&lq=1))
It is a struggle to access and connect each device (especially 50 of them),
and I thus need to be able to reflash a program to them via the commandline of an RPi.

I have bootloaded them all from my windows 10 machine and can flash any program via USB.

## RPis

I have flashed programs from the RPi with an Arduino Uno, both with the IDE and avrdude.
 Arduino and avrdude are installed and working (installed both with apt-get).

The RPi can run an already flashed program, with reading and writing
 possible from the USB device.
 When plugged in the device is viewed by the lsusb command for 5 seconds.
 The pre-flashed program then runs and lsusb shows no device:

**`lsusb` immediately after device is plugged into port**

```
 pi@raspberrypi:/usr/bin $ lsusb
 Bus 001 Device 005: ID 046d:c077 Logitech, Inc.
 Bus 001 Device 006: ID 413c:2011 Dell Computer Corp. Multimedia Pro Keyboard
 Bus 001 Device 004: ID 413c:1005 Dell Computer Corp. Multimedia Pro Keyboard Hub
 Bus 001 Device 007: ID 16d0:0753 MCS Digistump DigiSpark
 Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0424:ec00 Standard Microsystems Corp. SMSC9512/9514 Fast Ethernet Adapter
 Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0424:9514 Standard Microsystems Corp.
 Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

**`lsusb` ~5 seconds after device is plugged into port**

```
 pi@raspberrypi:/usr/bin $ lsusb
 Bus 001 Device 005: ID 046d:c077 Logitech, Inc.
 Bus 001 Device 006: ID 413c:2011 Dell Computer Corp. Multimedia Pro Keyboard
 Bus 001 Device 004: ID 413c:1005 Dell Computer Corp. Multimedia Pro Keyboard Hub
 Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0424:ec00 Standard Microsystems Corp. SMSC9512/9514 Fast Ethernet Adapter
 Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0424:9514 Standard Microsystems Corp.
 Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

#### udev rules

I have followed the
[tutorial for udev rules by digistump](http://digistump.com/wiki/digispark/tutorials/linuxtroubleshooting)
and placed the file at /etc/udev/rules.d/49-micronucleus.rules

UDEV of [tinseey](https://www.pjrc.com/teensy/49-teensy.rules) (similar to bootloaded micronucleus for attiny167)

## AVR Device

[this post](http://www.raspberry-pi-geek.com/Archive/2014/03/Adding-analog-input-to-the-Pi-using-the-Digispark/(offset)/2)
hints it may not be possible,
however this issue may have been resolved, as I am using an attiny167 (rather than an 85),
and the Pi does not reboot on the USB being plugged in.

On using dmesg you can see it is unable to enumerate.
`dmesg`

```
[ 9820.701327] usb 1-1.2: new low-speed USB device number 7 using dwc_otg
[ 9820.803813] usb 1-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=16d0, idProduct=0753
[ 9820.803838] usb 1-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
[ 9825.208851] usb 1-1.2: USB disconnect, device number 7
[ 9828.001334] usb 1-1.2: new low-speed USB device number 8 using dwc_otg
[ 9833.081359] usb 1-1.2: device descriptor read/64, error -110
[ 9833.271389] usb 1-1.2: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[ 9833.461352] usb 1-1.2: new low-speed USB device number 9 using dwc_otg
[ 9833.541349] usb 1-1.2: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[ 9833.731352] usb 1-1.2: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[ 9833.921349] usb 1-1.2: new low-speed USB device number 10 using dwc_otg
[ 9834.341388] usb 1-1.2: device not accepting address 10, error -71
[ 9834.421361] usb 1-1.2: new low-speed USB device number 11 using dwc_otg
[ 9834.841371] usb 1-1.2: device not accepting address 11, error -71
[ 9834.841480] usb 1-1-port2: unable to enumerate USB device
```

## avrdude

I'm using the command, with different serial ports

```
usr/bin/avrdude -p attiny167 -c arduino -C /etc/avrdude.conf -b 19200 -P [COM PORT] -U flash:w:[MyHexFile.ino.hex]:i
```

this gives the error

```
avrdude: ser_open(): can't open device "[COM PORT]": No such file or directory

avrdude done.  Thank you.
```

The same method works with the Uno on the Pi, and the AVR device on my windows 10 machines.

I have updated the configuration file `avrdude.conf` to include the attiny167,
as I did with my windows 10 machine.

## Serial port

serial and ttyACMO appears with Uno in /dev, not for the AVR device.

## Arduino IDE

I've attempted to do this through the IDE but get the error:

```
/home/pi/Downloads/arduino-1.8.1/arduino-builder -dump-prefs -logger=machine -hardware /home/pi/Downloads/arduino-1.8.1/hardware -hardware /home/pi/.arduino15/packages -tools /home/pi/Downloads/arduino-1.8.1/tools-builder -tools /home/pi/Downloads/arduino-1.8.1/hardware/tools/avr -tools /home/pi/.arduino15/packages -built-in-libraries /home/pi/Downloads/arduino-1.8.1/libraries -libraries /home/pi/Arduino/libraries -fqbn=digistump:avr:digispark-tiny -ide-version=10801 -build-path /tmp/arduino_build_279218 -warnings=none -prefs=build.warn_data_percentage=75 -prefs=runtime.tools.micronucleus.path=/home/pi/.arduino15/packages/digistump/tools/micronucleus/2.0a4 -prefs=runtime.tools.avr-gcc.path=/home/pi/.arduino15/packages/arduino/tools/avr-gcc/4.8.1-arduino5 -verbose /home/pi/sensicorn/sensicorn/indoorSoftware/Arduino Code/neopixel_simple/neopixel_simple.ino
/home/pi/Downloads/arduino-1.8.1/arduino-builder -compile -logger=machine -hardware /home/pi/Downloads/arduino-1.8.1/hardware -hardware /home/pi/.arduino15/packages -tools /home/pi/Downloads/arduino-1.8.1/tools-builder -tools /home/pi/Downloads/arduino-1.8.1/hardware/tools/avr -tools /home/pi/.arduino15/packages -built-in-libraries /home/pi/Downloads/arduino-1.8.1/libraries -libraries /home/pi/Arduino/libraries -fqbn=digistump:avr:digispark-tiny -ide-version=10801 -build-path /tmp/arduino_build_279218 -warnings=none -prefs=build.warn_data_percentage=75 -prefs=runtime.tools.micronucleus.path=/home/pi/.arduino15/packages/digistump/tools/micronucleus/2.0a4 -prefs=runtime.tools.avr-gcc.path=/home/pi/.arduino15/packages/arduino/tools/avr-gcc/4.8.1-arduino5 -verbose /home/pi/sensicorn/sensicorn/indoorSoftware/Arduino Code/neopixel_simple/neopixel_simple.ino
Using board 'digispark-tiny' from platform in folder: /home/pi/.arduino15/packages/digistump/hardware/avr/1.6.7
Using core 'tiny' from platform in folder: /home/pi/.arduino15/packages/digistump/hardware/avr/1.6.7
Detecting libraries used...
"/home/pi/.arduino15/packages/arduino/tools/avr-gcc/4.8.1-arduino5/bin/avr-g++" -c -g -Os -w -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections  -w -x c++ -E -CC -mmcu=attiny85 -DF_CPU=16500000L -DARDUINO=10801 -DARDUINO_AVR_DIGISPARK -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR  "-I/home/pi/.arduino15/packages/digistump/hardware/avr/1.6.7/cores/tiny" "-I/home/pi/.arduino15/packages/digistump/hardware/avr/1.6.7/variants/digispark" "/tmp/arduino_build_279218/sketch/neopixel_simple.ino.cpp" -o "/dev/null"
Generating function prototypes...
"/home/pi/.arduino15/packages/arduino/tools/avr-gcc/4.8.1-arduino5/bin/avr-g++" -c -g -Os -w -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections  -w -x c++ -E -CC -mmcu=attiny85 -DF_CPU=16500000L -DARDUINO=10801 -DARDUINO_AVR_DIGISPARK -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR  "-I/home/pi/.arduino15/packages/digistump/hardware/avr/1.6.7/cores/tiny" "-I/home/pi/.arduino15/packages/digistump/hardware/avr/1.6.7/variants/digispark" "/tmp/arduino_build_279218/sketch/neopixel_simple.ino.cpp" -o "/tmp/arduino_build_279218/preproc/ctags_target_for_gcc_minus_e.cpp"

fork/exec /home/pi/.arduino15/packages/arduino/tools/avr-gcc/4.8.1-arduino5/bin/avr-g++: no such file or directory
Error compiling for board Digispark (Default - 16.5mhz).
```

when I type `which avr-g++`: /usr/bin/avr-g++, this is just a copy from my windows machine.
I found this [github issue](https://github.com/Robot-Will/Stino/issues/275)
and it seems to be irrelevant for now, just a path issue.

I've had to use a custom json file for the board manager to find micronucleus and Digispark Pro.

When I plug in the AVR device no new serial port is shown in Tools->Port (unlike Arduino UNO, ttyACM0 appears).

I'd much prefer to do flash via avrdude or similar on the commandline, so I have not focused on this.

---

## My question

Is it possible to flash the AVR device with a Raspberry Pi over USB?
If so, what am I doing wrong?